# Controlar caracteres string c#

Tags: c#

mi duda es como puedo hacer para controlar la cantidad de caracteres, por ej cuando le pido que me ingrese matricula deba ingresarme ASD (solo 3 caracteres) y no ASDASF(así estaría mal)

```
 Console.Write("Ingrese matricula del vehiculo : ");
                    matricula = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (matricula == "")
                        mensaje = "La matricula es obligatoria\n";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la propiedad `Length` para saber la cantidad de caracteres de un `String`:

```
Console.Write("Ingrese matricula del vehiculo : ");
 matricula = Console.ReadLine();
 if (matricula == "")
    mensaje = "La matricula es obligatoria\n";
 else if(matricula.Length > 3)
   mensaje = "La matricula solo puede tener 3 caracteres";
```

Comment: @Elner muchas gracias me sirvio, para un int se puede hacer lo mismo?

Comment: Para un `int`? A que te refieres?

Comment: @Elner Si se puede aplicar a un int eso mismo

Comment: Si te refieres a saber la cantidad de caracteres de un int32 puedes hacerlo con el método ToString() y te dará los números como string.